# How to highlight the intersections between two surfaces in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to see the intersection of a 3D function g with the plane z=0.

```
En[a_, ru_] := (ru^(3/2) - 2*ru^(1/2) + a)/(ru^(3/4)*
     Sqrt[ru^(3/2) - 3*ru^(1/2) + 2*a]);
L[a_, ru_] := (ru^(2) - 2*a*ru^(1/2) + a^2)/(ru^(3/4)*
     Sqrt[ru^(3/2) - 3*ru^(1/2) + 2*a]);
\[Rho][a_, r_] := r^2 + a^2 + 2*a^2/r;
\[CapitalDelta][a_, r_] := r^2 - 2*r + a^2;
ra[a_, ru_] := (2*(a*En[a, ru] - L[a, ru])^2)/(ru^2*(1 - En[a, ru]^2));
Rr[a_, ru_, r_] := -(1 - En[a, ru]^2)*r^4 + 
   2*r^3 - (a^2*(1 - En[a, ru]^2) + L[a, ru]^2)*r^2 + 
   2*r*(a*En[a, ru] - L[a, ru])^2;
\[Upsilon][a_, ru_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[Rr[a, ru, r]/(r*\[CapitalDelta][a, r]) + 
    L[a, ru]^2/\[Rho][a, r]];
\[Gamma][a_, ru_, r_] := 1/Sqrt[1 - \[Upsilon][a, ru, r]^2];
Nr[r_, a_] := Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta][a, r]/\[Rho][a, r]];
Nf[r_, a_] := -2*a/(r*\[Rho][a, r]);
gtphi[a_, RS_] := -2*a/RS;
gphiphi[a_, RS_] := \[Rho][a, RS];
gtt[a_, RS_] := -(1 - 2/RS);
\[CapitalOmega]max[a_, 
   RS_] := (-gtphi[a, RS] + 
     Sqrt[gtphi[a, RS]^2 - gphiphi[a, RS]*gtt[a, RS]])/
   gphiphi[a, RS];
bb[a_, RS_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := -(gtphi[a, RS] + 
      gphiphi[a, RS]*\[CapitalOmega])/(gtt[a, RS] + 
     gtphi[a, RS]*\[CapitalOmega]);
\[Beta][r_, RS_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  ArcCos[bb[a, RS, \[CapitalOmega]]*
    Nr[r, a]/(Sqrt[\[Rho][a, r]]*(1 + 
         bb[a, RS, \[CapitalOmega]]*Nf[r, a]))];
Ar[a_, ru_, r_, RS_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := \[Gamma][a, ru, r] - 
   Sqrt[Rr[a, ru, r]]*Sin[\[Beta][r, RS, a, \[CapitalOmega]]]/r - 
   L[a, ru]*Cos[\[Beta][r, RS, a, \[CapitalOmega]]]/Sqrt[\[Rho][a, r]];
g[a_, ru_, r_, 
   RS_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := (2*a*L[a, ru] - 
      r*\[Rho][a, r]*En[a, ru])*(1/\[Gamma][a, ru, r] - 
      Ar[a, ru, r, RS, \[CapitalOmega]]) +
   ((r - 2)*L[a, ru] + 
      2*a*En[a, ru])*(Cos[\[Beta][r, RS, a, \[CapitalOmega]]] - 
      L[a, ru]*
       Ar[a, ru, r, RS, \[CapitalOmega]]/Sqrt[\[Rho][a, r]]) + (Sqrt[
       Rr[a, ru, r]]*\[CapitalDelta][a, r]/
       r)*(Sin[\[Beta][r, RS, a, \[CapitalOmega]]] - 
      Sqrt[Rr[a, ru, r]/\[CapitalDelta][a, r]]*
       Ar[a, ru, r, RS, \[CapitalOmega]]/r);

Z1[a_] := 1 + (1 - a^2)^(1/3)*((1 + a)^(1/3) + (1 - a)^(1/3));
Z2[a_] := Sqrt[3*a^2 + Z1[a]^2];
rISCO[a_] := 3 + Z2[a] - Sqrt[(3 - Z1[a])*(3 + Z1[a] + 2*Z2[a])];
rIBCO[a_] := 2 - a + 2*Sqrt[1 - a];
rH[a_] := 1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2];
barR[a_] := rIBCO[a] + 2/5*(rIBCO[a] + rISCO[a]);
RS = 6;
a = 0.2;
ru = barR[a] - 0.001;
\[CapitalOmega]max[a, RS];
```

After defined the function g, I do the following plot:

```
Plot3D[{g[a, ru, r, RS, \[CapitalOmega]], 0}, {r, ru, 
  ra[a, ru]}, {\[CapitalOmega], 0, \[CapitalOmega]max[a, RS]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{ru, ra[a, ru]}, {0, 0.14}, {-20, 20}}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[20, Black], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[Rotate["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"r\",\nFontColor->GrayLevel[0]]\) (M)", 0 Degree]], 
   Style[Rotate[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(\[FivePointedStar]\)]\
\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(M\), \(-1\)]\))", 65 Degree]], 
   Style[Rotate["g", 0 Degree]]}, ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red}]
```

The result of the plot is the following
[image]

Now how can I highlight the intersection between the function g (yellow surface) and the plane z=0 (blue surface).

Comment: just add the option `Mesh -> {{0}}`?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the option `Mesh -> {{0}}`

```
Plot3D[{g[a, ru, r, RS, Ω], 0}, {r, ru, ra[a, ru]}, {Ω, 0, Ωmax[a, RS]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{ru, ra[a, ru]}, {0, 0.14}, {-20, 20}}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> {Red}]
```

to get

[image]

If you need the additional mesh lines you can style the line corresponding to `z=0` differently:

```
Plot3D[{g[a, ru, r, RS, Ω], 0}, {r, ru, ra[a, ru]}, {Ω, 0, Ωmax[a, RS]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{ru, ra[a, ru]}, {0, 0.14}, {-20, 20}}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
 Mesh -> {Append[{#, Orange} & /@ FindDivisions[{-20, 20}, 10], {0, 
     Directive[Red, Thick]}]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]